# Aggregate the columns we create with pivot_wider (set a difference)

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

In my dataset i have individuals with sometimes 2 timepoints, and i would like to set the difference between the 2 timepoints. The thing is that i have a lot of columns which i would like to apply this on.
In my dataset i have or 1 or 2 rows per individuals, here is an example of what i have done with 2 colums :

```
library(tidyr)
data = data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6),
                  time = c("M0","M3","M0","M3","M0","M0","M0","M3","M0"),
                  bio1 = c(4.2, 4.8, 4, NA, 3.8, 4.4, 5, 6, 6.1),
                  bio2 = c(12, 14, 10, 11, NA, 18, 19, 12, 15))
data 

data_wide <- data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="time",
              values_from=c("bio1","bio2")) %>%
  mutate(diff_bio1 = bio1_M3 - bio1_M0,
         diff_bio2 = bio2_M3 - bio2_M0) %>%
  select(id, diff_bio1, diff_bio2)
data_wide
```

I know with pivot_wider we can aggregate function on every seperated columns we create, but i didn't find a way to apply the function directly at the creation to set the difference. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least using Tidyverse functions, a repeated operation across pairs of columns can be trickier than a solution that doesn't reshape the data wider:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6),
                  time = c("M0","M3","M0","M3","M0","M0","M0","M3","M0"),
                  bio1 = c(4.2, 4.8, 4, NA, 3.8, 4.4, 5, 6, 6.1),
                  bio2 = c(12, 14, 10, 11, NA, 18, 19, 12, 15))

df |> 
  complete(id, time) |> 
  arrange(id, time) |> 
  summarize(across(starts_with("bio"), diff),
            .by = id)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>      id   bio1  bio2
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1  0.600     2
#> 2     2 NA         1
#> 3     3 NA        NA
#> 4     4 NA        NA
#> 5     5  1        -7
#> 6     6 NA        NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks it works well on my data, the trick with complete() i didn't know

Answer (score 2):

```
fn <- function(.x) if(length(.x)>1) diff(.x) else NA

data%>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('bio'), fn , .names = 'diff_{col}'), .by=id)

  id diff_bio1 diff_bio2
1  1       0.6         2
2  2        NA         1
3  3        NA        NA
4  4        NA        NA
5  5       1.0        -7
6  6        NA        NA
```

---

```
data %>%
   mutate(time='diff')%>%
   pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = time, values_fn = fn, 
              values_from = starts_with('bio'), names_glue = "{time}_{.value}")

# A tibble: 6 × 3
     id bio1_diff bio2_diff
  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1     0.600         2
2     2    NA             1
3     3    NA            NA
4     4    NA            NA
5     5     1            -7
6     6    NA            NA
```